# What are these two athletes talking about?

Tags: cipher, real

[image]

Fernando Alonso and Esteban Ocon are currently the two drivers driving for Alpine Racing Team in the 2021 Formula 1 season.

Earlier today, Fernando and Esteban had [this conversation](https://twitter.com/alo_oficial/status/1430450484020711425) in clearly coded terms. It has since been determined that this is indeed real and they were not hacked.

To make it easier, this is a Cipher that uses a keyword and that keyword is already part of the body of this question.

Can you find out what they were talking about?

> P.S. - Please don't try to check for the answer on Twitter since a
> number of users have already solved this.

---

Text transcription:

> FERNANDO: BTV vras nduvrg ddwa. Eno iw giadt gby awa, Q’z xwptbvrg ewqf mn ndlr!!!!
> ESTEBAN: I mtb lsu pkmecoyt evpl hdzx sue lpnx yzj’zr enydcagiyv agvatvpg ewln 
> FERNANDO:   Lpi’a fie, wtb’f wep. Iprc’vp vwg 24 lofga gs wzgs vx ofi!

Comment: Could use a text transcription

Comment: I added one. I hope I didn't make mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cipher is:

> Vigenere with key `ALPINE`

The messages are:

> @alo_oficial: BIG news coming soon. And to tease you all, I’m tweeting this in code!!!!
>  @OconEsteban: I bet you everyone will work out what you’re announcing straight away 
>  @alo_oficial:   Let’s see, let’s see. They’ve got 24 hours to work it out!